# Cannot activate kivy environment on windows

Tags: python, windows-10, kivy

I recently installed kivy on my windows 10 machine using pip but I am not able to activate it and run a simple test program.

This is the folder where it is installed:

```
C:\Users\sumichop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy
```

even running `kivy --version` on the command line gives me the error:

> 'kivy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is the simple python script I wrote:

```
from kivy.app import App
App().run()
```

Comment: Take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman/41461002#41461002

Comment: Kivy is a python module - you need to import it in a python program and then run that program with the python interpreter.